# AS3 detect ipad or iphone in Flash Professional CS6

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, ipad, flash, air

Using Flash Professional CS6, I've created a game that looks and plays great on an iPad 2 and 3.  So now I'm ready to make the app "Universal" by making one that works better for the smaller screen on iPhones.

What I'd like to do, is detect in my first frame something like this:

```
if iPhone {
gotoAndPlay(2, "Scene 1");
}
else if iPad {
gotoAndPlay(3, "Scene 2");
}
else {
trace("Not an iOS Device");
}
```

If seen posts from 2010 where people retrieved the height and width of the device in px, but surely there's a better way right?

Answer (score 0):

[Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html) class has useful info. The os property should help determine the device but you'll need to experiment to see what each device returns.

However, i would suggest basing logic on screen size rather than device type - that way its more flexible.